# How to Install Enterprise App (.ipa) on iPad

Tags: ipad, installation, enterprise, ipa

I have an Enterprise iPhone app (.ipa file) that could run on iPad in compatibility mode. What app could an enduser use to install the .ipa on iPad -  apart from over-the-air?

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Check for [i-FunBox](http://www.i-funbox.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just distribute the IPA through mail. End user can copy the app on her iTunes and just do a sync, as with regular App store apps.

Comment: Silly question of mine, sorry. Just plug iPad into laptop, File > Add File to Library and sync with iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

There are online tools that simplify this process of sharing, for example https://abbashare.com or https://diawi.com
Create an ipa file from xcode with adhoc or inhouse profile, and upload this file on these site.
I prefer abbashare because save file on your dropbox and you can delete it whenever you want

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a [questions and answers site](http://stackoverflow.com/about), not a link collection. Please include relevant content in your answer, not just a link to where the content may be. The link is nice to have in addition for reference or for further information. For more tips, see [How to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer).